# Multi line in anchor tag

Tags: html

How to set a multi line string in an anchor tag without breaking it into a single line.?

```html
<a href="" >Amazon 
Catalog AD 7 </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<br>` tag within `<a> </a>` tag. Try the following:

```html
 <a href="" >Amazon 
       <br> Catalog AD 7 </a>
```

Whenever you need a new line. You can add `<br>` tag.